# How to add and apply breadcrumbs.phtml to child theme in Magento 2?

Tags: php, xml, magento

I have a Magento 2 theme I'm using for the design, and have a child theme created that I'm working off of. I am trying to modify the breadcrumbs html so I can extend some additional classes to it. I can't find any breadcrumbs.phtml file in the parent theme, but I did find it in the vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/template/html directory.

My question becomes, how can I create a new breadcrumbs.phtml file for my new child theme and where do I add it to the xml so it will be reflected on the frontend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to override template, then you do not need to add it in xml, just copy the `breadcrumb.phtml` file to your theme's directory and you can modify it in your theme.

You can put your `breadcrumb.phtml` file at below path.

> `app\design\frontend\<VENDOR_NAME>\<THEME_NAME>\Magento_Theme\templates\html\`

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that a different PHTML file is used on product pages:

`/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/breadcrumbs.phtml`